# Webpack 4: How to use ExtractTextPlugin.extract()

Tags: webpack

I am migrating my project from Webpack 3 to Webpack 4, and I want to replace `extract-text-webpack-plugin` with `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

My webpack config has this section

```
if (options.extract) {
  return ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: loaders,
    fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
  })
} else {
  return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders)
}
```

Obviously I cannot perform a `return MiniCssExtractPlugin.extract({/*..*/})`.

What is the equivalent syntax for `mini-css-extract-plugin`?

Complete webpack configuration https://gist.github.com/hanxue/74691af423247c9028c7ff811f373608

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change `generateLoaders` to

```
function generateLoaders (loader, loaderOptions) {
    const loaders = [cssLoader]

    if (loader) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: loader + '-loader',
        options: Object.assign({}, loaderOptions, {
          sourceMap: options.sourceMap
        })
      })
    }

    // Extract CSS when that option is specified
    // (which is the case during production build)

    if (options.extract) {
      return [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader].concat(loaders)
    } else {
      return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Won't your change means there the `postcss-loader` will not be used ever?

Comment: If you want to use postcss, you can manually add 
` const postcssLoader = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }
` and replace in `const loaders = [cssLoader]`